# Can I install both High Sierra and Mavericks on my Mac?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, partition, apfs

I have a 2013 MacBook Pro with both Mavericks and El Capitan installed (each on their own partition).

I now want to use Mavericks and High Sierra, each on their own partition.

Since High Sierra uses the APFS file system, will this prove to be a problem? Will it conflict with the HFS format use in Mavericks?

If there would be a conflict, how could I use both High Sierra and Mavericks on the one MacBook?

Comment: Is your internal drive a HDD or SSD? Are you using encryption? Could you edit your answer and include the output from `diskutil list`.

Comment: i use drive ssd 1tb / im not use encryprion,

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use APFS to run High Sierra. Although, I believe if your internal drive is  a SSD, then the High Sierra installer will try to convert the existing El Capitan partition and El Capitan Recovery partition to a APFS container partition.

Upgrading El Capitan to High Sierra should not effect Mavericks.

> Note: Mojava (macOS 10.14) will be released on September 24, 2018

Comment: There's at least one possible complication: since Mavericks doesn't support APFS, if the High Sierra partition does get converted, Mavericks won't be able to mount that volume *or select it in the Startup Disk preferences*. That means that to switch from Mavericks to High Sierra will require holding the Option key at startup.

Comment: @Gordon Davission: Another work around would be install rEFInd. You could select rEFInd from Mavericks and configure rEFInd to silently boot High Sierra.